# Electrostatic potential of finite charged wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, integration

So I was trying to find the electric potential at any point $\boldsymbol{x}$ of a charged wire of length $L$ at the $z$ axis, from $-L/2$ to $L/2$, and I had to write it down in terms of elliptic integrals. Thing is, the potential formula is

$$\phi(\boldsymbol{x}) = \dfrac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \int \dfrac{\rho(x')}{|\boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{x'}|} d^3x',$$

and considering the linear case of a wire, I wrote

$$\phi(\boldsymbol{x}) = \dfrac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \int_{-L/2}^{L/2} \dfrac{\lambda(z')}{\sqrt{r^2 + (z-z')^2}}dz',$$

where I considered $\boldsymbol{x} = (x, y, z)$ and $\boldsymbol{x'} = (0, 0, z')$, which gave me that $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$. But the integral form of this potential is hyperbolic, right? I don't understand how we could write this potential in terms of elliptic integrals, unless I did something wrong or the question mentioned the wrong type of integrals to find.

Comment: If you want elliptic integrals, then consider choosing $\lambda$ to be non uniform. For example, if you take $\lambda = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$ you'll get an elliptic integral of the first kind. Perhaps double check the question.

Comment: Right, and if $\lambda(z') = \sqrt{1 - (z')^2}$ then we would have a type 2 elliptic integral? Doesn't this interfere with the hyperbolic part of the integral? How can we for sure say if $\lambda(z')$ being what you said and being what I said here will result in a elliptic integral?

Comment: See my calculations based ellipsoidal or cylindrical coordinates [*here*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/399532/electric-field-generated-by-a-uniform-rod/399581#399581).

Answer (score 0):

My description was very different from the questioner's question, I am deleting most of the description. sorry.

================

I know the formula for the electric field vector, not the electric scalar potential $\phi$.
Provided that  $\lambda$ is constant along the line, the $\vec{E}$ formula is given as (lines deleted below.)

Comment: I appreciate your answer but unfortunately it's not what I was looking for. I don't need to find the electric field, just the potential of said wire at a point in space, and I cannot assume $\lambda$ is constant as I need to represent said potential in terms of elliptic integrals. If $\lambda$ is constant we would have a hyperbolic integral, so the linear charge distribution must not be constant.