# Charge distribution on an infinitesimally thin, elliptical conducting thread

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, coulombs-law

Assume an elliptical conducting thread, which is positively charged. Although the thread is considered to be very thin, its stiffness is great enough in order not to allow the Coulomb's forces between the charges to deform its elliptical shape. It is evident that there is a specific linear charge density ($\lambda$) for the distribution of the charges on this thread, which, contrary to a charged conducting plate/sphere/etc, tends *not* to necessarily nullify the electric field everywhere inside this closed thread.

However, it is evident that, due to the Coloumb's force, there should be a unique $\lambda$ as a function of $\theta$, where $\theta$ can be an arbitrary angle relative to the horizontal at the center of the ellipse. Recall that the ellipse itself has the following equation with a polar form relative to the center: [[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Polar_forms)

$$r(\theta)=\frac{b}{\sqrt{1 - (e\cos\theta)^2}}$$

I want to know:

**1. Is it possible to apply the Poisson equation to determine $\lambda (\theta)$?**

If so, how can we replace the surface charge density that traditionally appears in the Poisson equation with a linear charge density? Is it easy to solve the relevant Poisson equation for this example? What is the solution?

**2. If the Poisson equation is not applicable to this example, how can we obtain $\lambda (\theta)$?**

Comment: Unlike elliptic disk, elliptic ring version seems to be unsolved.  You may refer to [*Thomson problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem) approach [*here*](https://www.scirp.org/journal/paperinformation.aspx?paperid=124742).

Comment: Regarding elliptic disk as a special case of oblate spheroid, the surface charge distribution is $$\sigma(x,y)=\frac{Q}{4\pi a b \sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}}}$$ For conducting rod, an extreme case of prolate spheroid, you may refer to my older post [*here*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/399532/electric-field-generated-by-a-uniform-rod/399581#399581).

Comment: Sorry to mess up the oblate spheroid case, the degenerate case of oblate spheroid is circular disk instead. $\\$

The equipotential surface for elliptic disk (which is known as the focal ellipse) should be the confocal ellipsoid, namely $$\frac{x^2}{a^2+s}+\frac{y^2}{b^2+s}+\frac{z^2}{s}=1$$